# dcos: springboot application, deployUCR : Unauthorized

Tags: spring-boot, dcos

When running the below command to deploy a springboot application, I endup getting Unauthorized error.

What config is missing?

mvn package dcos:uploadArtifact **dcos:deployUCR**

```
[INFO] --- dcos-maven-plugin:0.6-SNAPSHOT:uploadArtifact (default-cli) @ springreactorcontext ---
[INFO] About to execute DC/OS pushArtifact.
[INFO] Uploading this file: /Volumes/data/projects/espre05/javanotes/springreactorcontext/target/springreactorcontext-1.0.jar
[INFO] Response from DC/OS [201] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- dcos-maven-plugin:0.6-SNAPSHOT:deployUCR (default-cli) @ springreactorcontext ---
[INFO] About to execute DC/OS deployUCR
[INFO] app definition: /Volumes/data/projects/esp/javanotes/springreactorcontext/application.json
[INFO] legacy default app definition: /Volumes/data/projects/esp/javanotes/springreactorcontext/app-definition.json
[INFO] dcos token: /Volumes/data/projects/esp/javanotes/springreactorcontext/.dcos-token
[INFO] dcos url: http://172.17.0.3
[INFO] ignore ssl certificate: true
[INFO] deployable: EMPTY
[INFO] TempFile: /var/folders/86/9nj0h71j6kz9grdp6zkg2tkm0000gq/T/ucr-deploy14723186433955340084json
[INFO] Calculated url: http://172.17.0.3/service/marathon/v2/apps/springreactorcontext
[INFO] Response from DC/OS [401] <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Unauthorized</title>
```

[image]